# user control using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a kind of user control using javascript.

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="text" id="myText" />
</div>
```

I want to insert this div in my HTML markup, wherever I required. Purpose is to make it reusable at various places in my HTML and maintain a single point of change, if I need to change the control in future. I would like to have a javascript function for it. I need best possible ways to do it maybe using jquery.

Comment: Sounds good. What is your question, dear writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is a decent candidate for the new [jQuery templates](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/04/new-official-jquery-plugins-provide-templating-data-linking-and-globalization/).  You can find [a tutorial here](http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html), for example:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div id="myDiv${ID}">
    <input type="text" id="myText${ID}" />
  </div>  
</script>
```

Then when using it, it would look like this:

```
$("#myTemplate").tmpl([{ID: 1}]).appendTo("#something");
```

This is just an example, your IDs should be unique and not duplicated anywhere in the page, even as a result of appending them through JavaScript.  If you want a template to reuse this is a pretty flexible way to do, more so if you're passing data as well, for example:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div id="myDiv${ID}">
    <input type="text" id="myText${ID}" value="${Val}" />
  </div>  
</script>
```

And just add that property in:

```
$("#myTemplate").tmpl([{ID: 1, Val: "Test"}]).appendTo("#something");
```

Or you could pass an array to [`.tmpl()`](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) to make many of these at once, as the result of a JSON response, etc.  Also based on your comment, yes you can also get the template from as an external file, [like this](http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need the clone() function
[Clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)